# Why does the "\left [" partially disappear when I color a row in a table? But [ does not disappear

Tags: tables, color, matrices, colortbl, bugs

The problem is shown in the picture below: the tall left-hand square brackets that should be produced by `\left[` and `\begin{bmatrix}` vanish.

[image]

The code is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\begin{sloppypar}
\rowcolors{2}{red!30}{blue!30}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
\hline
\textbf{Column-Title} & \textbf{title} \\
\hline
Content & 
\[
\left[\begin{matrix}
1
\end{matrix}
\right]\]
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2
\end{bmatrix}

[ ]
\]
\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The problem with the tall left-hand square brackets not showing up also arises in the following, much-streamlined version of the code given above. Oddly, the problem disappears if the `\rowcolor` directive is either omitted or is replaced with `\cellcolor`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' and 'bmatrix' environments
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
    \rowcolor{red!25}
    $\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 \end{matrix} \right] \quad [\,]$ \\[1ex]
    \rowcolor{blue!25}
    $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2 \end{bmatrix} \quad [\,]$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: There is a mistake in your code. Paragraphs (empty lines) are not allowed inside `\[…\]`. However, fixing this, would not solve the main issue.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of posting an addendum to demonstrate/confirm that the problem also arises in a much-streamlined test document. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using \cellcolor will solve my urgent need for now.

Comment: the problem is not related to `\left`, a simple x before the matrix would disappear too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`matrix` has a negative space which is causing the background to over-print, but you don't really want to redraw the background on nested tables anyway, so this disables it

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' and 'bmatrix' environments
\makeatletter
\def\notmyfault{\let\CT@@do@color\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
    $\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 \end{matrix} \right] \quad [\,]$ \\[1ex]
    \rowcolor{red!25}\notmyfault
    $\left[\begin{matrix} 1 \end{matrix} \right] \quad [\,]$ \\[1ex]
    \rowcolor{blue!25}\notmyfault
    $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2 \end{bmatrix} \quad [\,]$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) for the time being. It's a workaround, rather than a solution.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[3cm] Q[c,3cm]},
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    row{odd[2-Z]} = {bg=blue!30},
    row{even[2-Z]} = {bg=red!30},
    vlines, hlines,
    }
    Column-Title & Title \\
    Content      & \(
                   \left[\begin{matrix}1\end{matrix}\right]
                   \) \\
    Xxxxx        & \(
                   \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}
                   \)
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (with the key `color-inside`, alias: `colortbl-like`), you will have directly the expected output (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz to color the cells, and not `colortbl`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix} % loads amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c}[color-inside]
    \rowcolor{red!25}
    $\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 \end{matrix} \right] \quad [\,]$ \\[1ex]
    \rowcolor{blue!25}
    $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2 \end{bmatrix} \quad [\,]$
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]